# Upload/download a whole folder with dropbox api core

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I wanted to know if there's any method in the dropbox api core to upload/download a whole folder.

Currently, I'm uploading/downloading files one by one but wanted to have the possibility of just doing it at once by means of gathering all in a folder and get it in/from dropbox.

I guess I could do so with some for-loop, recurrent calls to a custom method hasSubfolders(), and using metada() and createFolder() method from the DropboxApi object but i wanted to be sure if Dropbox Api enables to use [putFile](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#putFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener%29) and [getFile](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener%29) with folders instead of just a file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method to download a full folder, so you'll have to write a loop.